# weka- replace null value in a nominal attribute with a string

Tags: weka, openrefine

I am cleaning a data set with google open refine and then trying to use it in Weka to do some cluster analysis.  I am dealing with a nominal column that stores range of salaries.
I've specified the attribute as below

```
@ATTRIBUTE Income {'0-30000','30000-50000','50000-75000','75000-150000','>150000'}
```

In the data set there are rows in which the 'Income' column is null and I suppose that is the reason why I get the error:

'nominal value not declared in header, read Token line 13'

Is there a way I can replace null values with a string( and then specify the string in the attribute)? - If so how do i specify it in the @ATRRIBUTE row? 
Or would it be possible to include the null in the set of attributes?

Thanks

Comment: I can't answer this in terms of Weka, so simply to comment that in OpenRefine you can replace null values using something like if(isNull(value),"REPLACEMENT STRING",value)

Comment: Thanks @OwenStephens.  This helps.